# La répétition du pronom relatif « qui » vis-à-vis d'une différence de voix

Tags: pronoms-relatifs, syntaxe, stylistique, voix-passive

Personnellement, j'aurais évité jusqu'à présent la tournure de la phrase suivante, bien que tout considéré elle ne comporte pas de défauts apparents de grammaire.

- Cette sonde émet des ultrasons qui traversent les tissus puis lui sont renvoyés sous la forme d'un écho.

On trouve dans LBU (section 711 a, 14ième édition) que le pronom relatif « qui » peut être répété ou non. Cependant, on y trouve aussi la remarque très intéressante suivante.

> Certains grammairiens exigent la répétition quand le temps des verbes est différent. L'usage ne tient pas compte de cette règle arbitraire : Cette œuvre, la France, QUI est et demeurera son propre mandataire, la poursuivra (DE GAULLE,
>   Disc, et messages, 15 févr. 1945).

J'ai en quelque sorte l'intuition que la teneur de la remarque citée, dont la justification ne s'impose pas clairement à mon esprit mais à laquelle  je suis porté à accorder un certain intérêt, irait plus loin que la différence de temps et s'étendrait dans le domaine de la voix, domaine dans lequel l'impression de ce qui serait pour le moins un style défaillant devient aiguë (plus gênante que dans le cas des différences de temps, pour lesquelles elle reste mal définie). 
Quelqu'un aurait peut-être  à ce sujet  la connaissance d'un courant d'esprit qui irait dans le sens de la remarque à la section 711 du LBU, mais  en ce qui concerne la voix passive. Existerait-il des prescriptions, mêmes non concrétisées dans l'usage, qui seraient favorables à la répétition et y aurait-il des raisons reconnues pour cela ? Un ajout d'opinions personnelles n'est pas inutile.

Comment: Je pense que ce serait bien de préciser ce qu'est le LBU.

Comment: @JulienLopez You can consult or  upload this reference for free using the following link:https://ia800206.us.archive.org/27/items/LeBonUsagefrenchpdf.com/Le_bon_usage%28frenchpdf.com%29.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Il n'y a pas beaucoup de littérature sur ce sujet mais j'ai pu accéder à une [source](http://www.gabrielwyler.com/page624.htm#Lacoordinationdessubordonn%C3%A9es-exameng%C3%A9n%C3%A9ral) qui tend à confirmer que la répétition du pronom est souhaitable.

> Si les sujets de deux propositions coordonnées sont identiques, leur réduction à un seul pronom relatif est chose facile. Cependant, si les deux propositions sont longues ou qu'elles ont des caractéristiques temporelles, aspectuelles ou logiques différentes, il vaut mieux les relativer indépendamment.

Il semble que l'on peut incriminer sur le plan d'une logique différente la nature différente des sujets dans les deux préposition : dans la première la « logique » du sujet est celle d'un *sujet qui accomplit l'action* alors que dans la seconde ce n'est que celle d'un *sujet qui subit l'action*.